# plot table from CSV in R (построить график с csv данных в R)

Tags: r, csv, график

Не могу построить график данных взятых с csv файла. Вот как беру данные:

```
nS <- read.csv(file="8.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";");
nS <- nS[,-1];
```

Получается вот такая таблица:

```
       Daily    Fact
1 01.01.2008 2060,54
2 02.01.2008 2321,89
3 03.01.2008 2465,55
4 04.01.2008 2629,14
```

Как построить график день/значение на языке R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- read.table(text = '       Daily    Fact
1 01.01.2008 2060,54
2 02.01.2008 2321,89
3 03.01.2008 2465,55
4 04.01.2008 2629,14', header = TRUE, dec = ",")
x$Daily <- as.Date(x$Daily, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

График стандартными средствами R:

```
plot(x = x$Daily, y = x$Fact, type = "p")
lines(x = x$Daily, y = x$Fact)
```

С помощью пакета `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x, aes(x = Daily, y = Fact)) +
    geom_point(stat = "identity") + 
    geom_line(stat = "identity")
```

Столбиковая диаграмма:

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = Daily, y = Fact)) +
    geom_col()
```

Comment: помогите пожалуйста. Сейчас ваш код строит график, но только датам сопоставляются цифры от 1 до 4, не значения столбца Fact.

Comment: Это потому что `Fact` считался как строка (фактор). Добавил `dec = ","`.

Comment: Для разделителя `";"` есть стандартная фенкция чтения `read.csv2()`

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov , Спасибо вам большое.

Comment: @ikashnitsky , понял, изучу.

Comment: @Version8 Если позволите совет, изучайте сразу `ggplot2` - оно того стоит

Comment: @ikashnitsky , спасибо, за совет, будет время - почитаю)